# Regex to match a pattern only if not part of a larger pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to figure out how to write a regex to match a pattern but only if it's not part of a larger pattern I'm not interested in.  For example, I'd like a regex which will match anything containing "foo" except for "foobar"

So it should match "foobaz" or "fooqux" but not "foobar"

Thanks!

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for, but I always just remove the ones I don't want in a second pass.  `grep foo | grep -v foobar`.

Comment: You could try something like `foo[^b][^a][^r], but it won't work quite right.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative lookahead here to match a word starting with `foo` but not `foobar`:

```
\bfoo(?!bar)\S*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mH7pT9/1)

**Breakup:**

```
\b        # word boundary
foo       # match literal text foo
(?!bar)   # negative lookahead to fail the match if we have bar ahead
\S*       # match 0 or more non-space characters
```